# Is it possible to use a variable as a string indice in Python?

Tags: python, string, variables

I'm really new to Python and programming in general, so I've been stuck for a while trying to figure out through searching the internet how to print a string to a length determined by a variable. This is one of the things I tried, for an example of what I'm attempting to do:

```
var1 = 6
string1 = "a random string"
print(string1[0,var1])
```

So I've been wondering if it is possible to use the stored value of a variable as a string indice or if there is another workaround that I haven't thought of or found on the rest of the internet.

Thanks for reading! :)

Comment: It should be `print(string1[0 : var1])` You should use `:` instead of `,`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that works. Some background about slices is available in the Python documentation for [Extended Slices](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html#extended-slices). But instead of the comma use `:`

```
var1 = 6
string1 = "a random string"
print(string1[0:var1])
# Output: a rand
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not using a variable as indice, but using tuple as indices, which you cannot do. If you wanna print the substring here's the code:

```
var1 = 6
string1 = "a random string"
print(string1[0:var1])
```